# Tastypie using custom detail_uri_name, mismatched type error

Tags: python, django, model, tastypie

I am trying to override `get_bundle_detail_data`

```
class MyResourse(ModelResource):
     foo = fields.CharField( attribute = 'modelA__variableOnModelA' )
     def get_bundle_detail_data(self, bundle):
         return bundle.obj.foo
     class Meta:
         resource_name='resource'
```

With the line of code `foo = fields.CharField( attribute = 'modelA__variableOnModelA' )`, I am setting the variable `foo` on the resource `MyResource`, to a variable on `modelA` called `variableOnModelA`. This works nicly.

But I am trying to make `variableOnModelA` be the identifier for `MyResource`, that way I can do `/api/v1/resource/bar/` to get the detailed `MyResource` with the variable `foo` set to `bar`.

The problem I am having is the error: `Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type).` What is this error saying?

**Ultimate Question:** How can I use `foo` as the `detail_uri_name`?

**EDIT**
Model:

```
class AgoraUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='agora_user')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'agora_users'
```

Urls:

```
full_api = Api(api_name='full')
full_api.register(AgoraUserResourse())
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(full_api.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(min_api.urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Actual Resource:

```
class AgoraUserResourse_min(ModelResource):
    username = fields.CharField(attribute = 'user__username' )
    class Meta:
        resource_name='user'
        #detail_uri_name = 'user__username'
        queryset = AgoraUser.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']
        authentication = AgoraAuthentication()
        authorization = AgoraAuthorization()
    def get_bundle_detail_data(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.username
```

Comment: Can you paste in your models and URL configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to override `detail_uri_kwargs` for your resource.

I wound up with something like this:

```
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.bundle import Bundle

from .models import AgoraUser


class AgoraUserResourse(ModelResource):
    username = fields.CharField(attribute='user__username')
    class Meta:
        resource_name='user'
        detail_uri_name = 'user__username'
        queryset = AgoraUser.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']
        # authentication = AgoraAuthentication()
        # authorization = AgoraAuthorization()

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            bundle_or_obj = bundle_or_obj.obj

        return {
            'user__username': bundle_or_obj.user.username
        }

    def get_bundle_detail_data(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.username
```

Comment: SO EASY! You saved me a bunch of time.